# How ro read mutli lined input into 2d arrays in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been across a problem in python,
the input format of the 2d  array to be read is

```
3           # number of rows and columns of a square matrix
1 2 3       # first row 
3 4 6       # second row
4 6 3       # third row
```

how do I read 2d array from the console like the above

Python Version : 3.6

IDE : Spyder (Python 3.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers are separated by a single space your can use the following code:

```
n = int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
  row = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
  matrix.append(row)
```

If you have different separator then space you can put as argument in the `split()` function.

Comment: Apparently, the example is now fixed, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())
matrix = dict()
for i in range(n):
    matrix["row"+str(i)] = input().split() # i assume you want the numbers seperated too
```

this take the number of lines input you want makes a dictionary with the number of inputs you initialy said

so matrix the dicitonary is now

```
{'row0': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
'row1': ['3', '4', '6', '9'], 
'row2': ['4', '6', '3', '1']}
```

incase you want them stored as intergers

```
n = int(input())
matrix = dict()
for i in range(n):
    matrix["row"+str(i)] = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

**output**

```
{'row0': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
'row1': [3, 4, 6, 9], 
'row2': [4, 6, 3, 1]}
```

or as a oneliner that just output list of lists

```
[[int(i) for i in input().split()] for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 6, 9], [4, 6, 3, 1]]
```

or as a dictionary oneliner

```
{'row'+str(q) : [int(i) for i in input().split()] for q in range(int(input()))}
```

**output**

```
{'row0': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'row1': [3, 4, 6, 9], 'row2': [4, 6, 3, 1]}
```

and as Patric pointed out a fast oneliner could be

```
{q : [int(i) for i in input().split()] for q in range(int(input()))}
```

**output**

```
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [3, 4, 6, 9], 3: [4, 6, 3, 1]}
```

this solution is faster because dictionaries uses hashes, and thus dont have to loop through the whole list before getting to the desired index.

Comment: how can I access an element belonging to second row and second column when I create an array by the above code?

Comment: you would just have to say matrix['row1'][1] since we in index start counting from 0

Comment: you could use `0`, `1`, `2` as key for the dicts first/second/third row, then something like `matrix[0][2]` would _simply work_ ... - still nice answer

Comment: @PatrickArtner if that is the bevior you want a list of list is more apropiet though in my oppinion

Comment: oh never mind i forgot about the fact that dicionaries uses hashes and thus uses O(1) soilutions stupid me xD